# Select rows where value changed in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Currently I have this table in sql database sorted by Account#.

```
Account#    Charge_code  PostingDate     Balance
  12345          35      1/18/2016       100
**12345          35      1/20/2016       200**
  12345          61      1/23/2016       250
  12345          61      1/22/2016       300
  12222          41      1/20/2016       200
**12222          41      1/21/2016       250**
  12222          42      1/23/2016       100
  12222          42      1/25/2016       600
```

How do I select last row prior to the change in the charge_code column for each Account#. I highlighted the rows that I am trying to return.

The query should execute quickly with the table having tens of thousands of records.

Comment: Do you mean selecting the last row sorted by PostingDate?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask].
Remember SO is not a free code service!

Comment: select a.[Account#]
,a.[Charge_Code]
,a.[PostingDate]
,a.[Balance]

from [dbo].[SampleTable] as a
cross join [dbo].[SampleTable] as b
where a.[Account#] = b.[Account#]
and a.[PostingDate] > b.[PostingDate]
and not exists (select * 
    from [dbo].[SampleTable] as c
    where a.[Account#] = c.[Account#]
    and a.[PostingDate] > c.[PostingDate]
    and c.[PostingDate] > b.[PostingDate]
)
and a.[Charge_Code] <> b.[Charge_Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(charge_code) over (partition by account order by postingdate) as next_charge_code
      from t
     ) t
where charge_code <> next_charge_code;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can do something similar with `apply`.